Is there a limit for an Update with Output SQL Statement
I want to update records on a view and get back the updated records to process them in my application, the code is working fine for almost cases, but for a specific senario when I have more than 22000 records on the view, 97 of them are not updated and not returned with the output of the query.
Is there a limit to using OUTPUT or what can be the issue?
public async Task<List<BatchRecord>> GetBatchRecordsAsync(string MW_Ref1)
    {
        string query = @"
            UPDATE MiddlewareRecords
            SET ForReuploadFlag = 0, 
                Rejected = 0, 
                RejectedRemarks = null, 
                CurrentStatus = 'Pending'
            OUTPUT deleted.*
            WHERE MW_Ref1 = @MW_Ref1";

        var results = await _connection.QueryAsync<BatchRecord>(query, new { MW_Ref1 }, transaction: _transaction);

        return results.ToList();
    }

The application is a .NET 6 application using Dapper to execute the query on MS SQL Server DB.
I tried for less records and it works fine.
But for these cases the records are not being fully updated,
Some of the records are updated and some are not.

No, there is not a limit. The fact the rows aren't being updated is why they aren't in the output, and if they aren't being updated then they don't meet the criteria of the WHERE/JOIN(s).

@ThomA actually when I make a SELECT statement by the same conditions all records are being returned
When I execute the update statement again the rest of the records get updated as well
So I don't think it's a problem with the WHERE clause

I suggest you take the time to create a [mre].

Sure I will work on one now

You say a view. You mean a literal view CREATE VIEW? Does that have a join in it? maybe the join is many to 1 for some of the rows hence more returned by the SELECT than affected by the UPDATE

@MartinSmith yes it's a view with join on it
Includes many to one but I am updating the many side of the join
So I think it should not effect the first table in the update statement

Is it possible that elsewhere in your code the session sets set rowcount 22000?

@OsamaAzab - Run the query and gather the actual execution plan and see where in the plan the row counts differ from what you expect.
